# Broadcast and answer with two threads and one shared variable

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, shared

Basically I am trying to send a broadcast message every second with one thread, and wait for an answer with another thread. The thing is I can't seem to get my code right, so I did a small example which would do the same thing, running two threads, one stopping when the other modified a certain variable. Here it is:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        test2 t = new test2();          
    }
}

public class test2 {
    private volatile Opponent b = new Opponent();

    public test2(){

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){  
            synchronized(this){
                while(!b.a){
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
                    System.out.println(i);

                    try{
                        this.wait(1000);
                    }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                    }

                }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){  
            synchronized(this){
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
                    System.out.println(i*100);

                    if(i*100 == 200){
                        b.a = true;
                        System.out.println("true");
                        }

                    try{
                        this.wait(1000);
                    }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }).start();
}
}
public class Opponent {

    static boolean a = false;

    public Opponent(){
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I do synchronized(this), the threads run, but the b.a is never updated, and the loop goes on forever. If I do synchronized(b), I get an IllegalMonitorException.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The field `Opponent.a` must be `volatile` as it is the variable that is being modified. In the posted code, the `volatile` applies to `test2.b` and would only be useful if new `Opponent` instances where being assigned to `test2.b`. The `volatile` on `test2.b` is useless and can be replaced with `final` as it does not change.

Note that as `Opponent.a` is a `static` an instance of `Opponent` does not actually need to be constructed.

Example correction:

```
// First thread loop condition.
//
while(!Opponent.a) {

// Second thread assignment.
//
Opponent.a = true;

public class Opponent
{   
    static volatile boolean a = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but still the loop runs forever. What should I do synchronized() on? If I don't do synchronized, I get an IllegalMonitorStateException